# Aparece error en QT

Tags: qt

Me muestra un mensaje y ni siquiera me aparece el compilador. Instale todo Visual Studio Community 2015 que sucede?

Este es el error que obtengo:

[image: Captura de pantalla del error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es configurar Qt para que sepa utilizar ese compilador.

Yo te diría de empezar pulsando el botón "Manage..." de la sección "compiler" de tu captura para elegir el compilador que se corresponde con la versión seleccionada. Si el compilador no se encuentra en la lista tendrás que añadir uno y configurarlo de forma manual indicando dónde se encuentra cada elemento:

- Ruta del compilador
- Ruta del make
- Tipo de compilación (esta opción creo que depende de la versión de QtCreator)
- Ruta de los ficheros de cabecera
- ...

Después de configurar el compilador correctamente podrás seleccionarlo desde la ventana que indicas y, en teoría, QtCreator debería ser capaz de compilar aplicaciones usando tu compilador.